# Laravel API routes 404 not found fix?

Tags: laravel, api, backend

I just uploaded Laravel Backend project which will be used for API only, but when I call any route from postman it says 404 not found and I can't catch the error reason

Laravel api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('/handle-register', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiAuthController@handleRegister');
Route::post('/handle-login', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiAuthController@handleLogin');

Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiUserController@index');
Route::post('/users-store', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiUserController@store');
```

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... is this a Laravel 404 page or a webserver 404 page?

Comment: please post the URL that you calling?

Answer (score -1):

There are some ways to use

1. Use Apache
2. run laravel server and use the server URL in the postman

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).